# Pass Complex Strings to React Object

Tags: reactjs

What is the syntax for passing complex strings as a prop to a react object?

For example, the string I want to pass is in the form of

```
Info [subinfo]
```

So I have the following:

```
<ViewSectionItem content={{item.Info} [{item.Subinfo}]} />
```

What would be the correct way to pass this string?  Or is the only way to pass it as 2 separate props?

Comment: what is the string? Info [subinfo] ?

Comment: Describe what "complex string" means according to you, because a string is always a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use backticks ` symbol so you can have:

```js
<ViewSectionItem content={`${item.Info} [$item.Subinfo]`} />
```